# sticky sections while scrolling, but overlayed by the one below

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a landing page. Each **section** should be **sticky while scrolling**. When the next sections should be sticky, too, but be over its parent section.

I found tons of jquery plugins that make the content sticky (e.g. fixTo). The problem here is, that the first section is always on top (no matter what z-index i give the tag). But I want the first section to be behind the second - hope you know what I mean...

Comment: Please post some code to show what you've already tried. A jsFiddle would be great.

Comment: This does not work due to fixto.js, fiddle says _Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbarakaci/fixto/master/dist/fixto.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled._ But I found the solution... so simple, I'll post it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you set a z-index for both div tags?

css

```
div1
    {
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        width:100px;
        z-index:1000;
    }

div2
    {
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        right:0px;
        width:100px;
        z-index:1001;
    }
```

Tested and it works, the 2nd div is above the first div.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to skibbi_bizzle for the hint. The solution is to give all the sections a negative zindex, starting with the lowest. And here's the code:

HTML:

```
<article id="main">
    <section class="wrapper" name="top" id="section-0">
         <h2>Top section</h2>

        <p>section content</p>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper style1" name="section-1" id="section-1">
         <h2>First section</h2>

        <p>section content</p>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper style2" name="section-2" id="section-2">
         <h2>Second section</h2>

        <p>section content</p>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper style3" name="section-3" id="section-3">
         <h2>Third section</h2>

        <p>section content</p>
    </section>
    <section class="wrapper style4" name="section-4" id="section-4">
         <h2>Fourth section</h2>

        <p>section content</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
#main {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
/* Wrapper */
 .wrapper {
    padding: 5em;
    color: inherit;
}
.wrapper.style1 {
    background: #aaa;
}
.wrapper.style2 {
    background: #bbb;
}
.wrapper.style3 {
    background: ccc;
}
.wrapper.style4 {
    background: #ddd;
}
section {
    width: 100%;
}
#section-0 {
    z-index: -10;
}
#section-1 {
    z-index: -9;
}
#section-2 {
    z-index: -8;
}
#section-3 {
    z-index: -7;
}
#section-4 {
    z-index: -6;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#section-0").fixTo("#main");
    $("#section-1").fixTo("#main");
    $("#section-2").fixTo("#main");
    $("#section-3").fixTo("#main");
    $("#section-5").fixTo("#main");
});
```